# Android application crashes on Volley JsonObject POST request

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying write a splash screen that attempts to authenticate the users' credentials if they exist already in SharedPreference, but the application shuts itself down without warning on the line the request is added to the RequestQueue. What should I do to resolve this issue?

```
File prefFile = new File("/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/shared_prefs/"+getPackageName()
            +"_preferences.xml");
    System.out.println(prefFile.toString());
    if(prefFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Found Preference File");
       final SharedPreferences pref = new SecurePreferences(getApplicationContext());

        Map<String, String> authParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        authParams.put("key", pref.getString("key",""));
        authParams.put("action", "validate");

        System.out.println("now authenticating");
        JsonObjectRequest authRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, AUTH_URL,
                new JSONObject(authParams), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
              /*  Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchScreen.this, BaseActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent); */
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                System.out.println(error.getMessage());
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization", "Token " + pref.getString("key",""));

                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };
        System.out.println("adding to queue");
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(authRequest);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Opening Login Activity");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without warning"? The console doesn't print any error?

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. No error is printed

Comment: In android studio, in the android monitor, where it says "show only selected application" set it to "No Filters" and let me know if it prints an error this time

Comment: There is still no error

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in the onErrorResponse method:

```
VolleyLog.e(error.getMessage());
```

Then, check your logs in Android ADB monitor